# Can't build a library with `stats-json`

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I would like to inspect my bundle in my Angular Library. It lives within a Nx Monorepo but I believe it is not relevant to the problem.

for my demo app I can do :

`nx run demo-app:build:production --statsJson`

everything works as expected, and my bundle have a stats.json.

Now, I am trying to do the same on my library

`nx run demo-lib:build:production --statsJson`

and the result is

```
'statsJson' is not found in schema

———————————————————————————————————————————————

>  NX   ERROR  Running target "any-ui:build" failed
```

Now, from what I heard [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15205) we can't use this flag on library ?

I then tried to use `--sourceMap=true` and source-map-explorer but still can't build.

How to analyze a library bundle in angular ?

Comment: The stats json is just for get a overview of the complexity of a application. a libary is mostly build with only the libary code so if we could build thoses statsjson ist would be very small and not very accurat. So you only can view the complete size of apps with the statsjson wich should always be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Cant be done Idk when it will change
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15205